# Is there a File explorer/Finder like tool for mac os, which can sort folders by name?

Tags: terminal, finder, folders

I couldn't figure it out how to sort folders by "name" in Finder. Now I know, that it's not possible. At least, according to what I think of, when I say sort by name. So I guess I need another tool.

> Substrings of digits are sorted according to their numeric value, as
>   opposed to sorting the actual characters in the number.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemDetails/FileSystemDetails.html)

My task is, to go trough hundreds of folders alphabetically, and look at an image within each folder, and check for errors.

My workflow currently is:

1. Copy the output of ls -la into excel
2. get the folder names
3. copy each row one by one into finder's search box
4. check the contents of the folder
5. I have a "notes" column in excel, where I can write my results

This is very tedious.

I would like to get the same sorting logic, as within in terminal.

Here are some sample folder names:

```
ls -la

...

0629e7bc-8110-4db9-aaa9-b67b0b73743d
06a409e1-98c6-4bf4-afa4-c814f7899d82
0a3a5c12-e459-4aa0-b9cb-30b544013215
0c14581f-31d8-4961-a14f-11afc40e47f9
0fe8970c-6338-46ca-bc16-f7867b271480
129855c4-7dbe-4a9f-a100-28b1d3d02340
1522e288-8a81-4298-aefc-f334cb088a53
180d430b-76f9-401f-845a-cb395bc1eba0
1a01a936-bedf-4758-971a-d4886ee8d281
```

[image: folders in Finder]

Could you recommend a tool, which can sort folders by name, alphabetically?
I've tried Commander One, but sadly, it's using the same logic as Finder.

Comment: Have you tried using the "ls" terminal command? If it sorts as you like you can easily redirect the output to a file...

Comment: We could modify the workflow itself in a way to avoid sorting if you could tell how many images do you have in any folder? We can open/close them using some python script and you can write the errors in the respective rows since you have folder names from the terminal output.

Comment: every folder has 1 image, in a series of sub folders. eg 0629e7bc-8110-4db9-aaa9-b67b0b73743d/v3/something/somethingElse/hereIsMyImage_with_a_random_filename.jpg

Comment: Why do you have to go in a specific order. Why can't you use another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope running this python script works. `TEST` would have all the folders you mentioned. I have modified the workflow slightly to avoid messing with  Finder and AppleScript. The final file can be opened in Excel.

```
import os
import fnmatch

import time
directory = "your/dirname/Desktop/TEST"
y = [x[0] for x in os.walk(directory)] 
y = y[1:]

#%%
thedict = {}
for one in y:
    thedict[one] = ""
#makes dictionary with all the folder names
for direc in thedict:
    matches = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(direc):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.jpg'):
            matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename)) 
    for photo in matches:
        stri = "open " + photo
        os.system(stri)
        error = raw_input("error?")
        thedict[direc] = error
#Photo opens, you see it, close it, type the error in terminal and hit #enter.
#Then the next one comes up.
import csv
with open('outputf.csv', 'w') as f:
    for key in thedict.keys():
        f.write("%s,%s\n"%(key,thedict[key]))
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! Small issues: I had python3 installed, and had to replace raw_input with input. When you are iterating over the folders, you are not filtering out folders which have no images in them. My images are in a series of sub folders, and only the deepest folders have images in them.